# How to run an R function from python with parameters?

Tags: python, r, subprocess

myScript.R:

```
model <- function(data)
{
      Do some stuff
}
```

Python:

```
import subprocess
def execution(data):
    exp=subprocess.Popen(["Rscript", "myScript.R"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1)
    for line in exp.stdout:
         if line[0:3]=="[1]":
            return line
```

how do I pass the data parameter to my R function?

Answer (score 0):

The package Rpy2 is good for this sort of thing, and the documentation regarding your question can be found here: https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html#calling-r-functions

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the python package rpy2, available from https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/ with documentation at https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/

The R package is widely available, either via pip or distribution repositories (including macports and standard linux distributions).

In your case,

```
from rpy2 import robjects as r
r.r.source('your_r_script.R')
```

At this stage, the functions contained in `your_r_script` are loaded in the `r.r' object, and you can access them as if you were in R:

```
output = r.r['your_function_name'](param1, param2, param3)
```

`output` will be a so-called r-object, which you will be able to access more or less straightforwardly depending on what it contains.

If it is a list, you access its coefficients with the method `rx2`, e.g.: `output.rx2(1)` will give you the first element of the list, and `output.rx2('param')` will give you the element of the list that is called 'param'. If this is an array, you use the method `rx`.

Again, see the [docs](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/).

Comment: I sadly want my code to run on Heroku and RPY2 does not install on Heroku so that really isn't an option.